# In Ruby on Linux, how can I check for the existence of a named network interface like eth0?

Tags: ruby, linux, networking

In ruby 1.8.5, how can I check for the existence of a named network interface like eth0 or wan0 under linux?  Even checking the existence would be a start.  I'm aware that I could wrap a shell command to use ifconfig or somesuch, but would rather have a pure ruby solution.

Another way of phrasing the question might be "If I was implementing ifconfig in ruby, what API would I use?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should look into the [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) tree, specifically in `/sys/class/net/`.

Comment: Thank you, both this and the /proc/net/dev suggestion look fine.  Do you happen to know which of /proc and /sys is less likely to change in future kernels?

Comment: I think /sys is the better choice (obviously), a lot of things under /proc (or perhaps all of it, I'm not quite sure) are deprecated.

Comment: I don't imagine /sys will change in future kernel releases; it's part of a design introduced in 2.6 as being "the right way to go"

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` opens `/proc/net/dev` and reads the interfaces out of there.

Answer (score 1):

```
%x[ifconfig eth0]
```

[Check this out.](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html)